Clarification on an argument in Opera de Cribro
In the beginning of Chapter 24 of Opera de Cribro, I am not able to understand why $\chi(a)=-1$ is not permissible? Why would the set $\mathcal{A}$ be empty in that case?
Relevant extract from the book:

(...)
Let $\chi \,(\operatorname{mod} q)$ be a real, non-principal character. Put
$$\lambda(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \chi(d)$$
We shall apply the sieve to the sequence $\mathcal{A} = (\lambda(n)a_n)$, where $a_n$ is the characteristic function of the arithmetic progression $n \equiv a \,(\operatorname{mod} q)$ with $(a,q) = 1$. Clearly, we must assume that
$$\chi(a) = 1$$
or else there is nothing in $\mathcal{A}$. (...)


If $\chi(a) = -1$, then $\chi(n) = -1$ since $n \equiv a \,(\operatorname{mod} q)$, thus $\chi(d) \chi(n/d) = \chi(n) = -1$, and so for each $d \mid n$ you have $\chi(d)= - \chi(n/d)$.
Consequently, since $\sqrt{n}$ cannot divide $n$ otherwise $0\le \chi(\sqrt{n})^2 = \chi(n) = -1$: $$\lambda(n) = \sum_{d\mid n \,;\, d < \sqrt{n}} \chi(d) + \sum_{d \mid n \,;\, d > \sqrt{n}} \chi(d) = \sum_{d\mid n \,;\, d < \sqrt{n}} \chi(d) + \sum_{d\mid n \,;\, d < \sqrt{n}} \chi(n/d) = 0$$
and $\mathcal{A}$ is the zero sequence.

Of course, that makes sense; I missed that. Thanks!
